# apt - Remove not configured package

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dpkg, apt

I have a Linux-Mint Debian Edition System. When I install sendmail I get an infinite loop.

```
Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
Validating configuration.
Creating /etc/mail/databases...
Reading configuration from /etc/mail/sendmail.conf.
Validating configuration.
Creating /etc/mail/databases...
```

When I try dpkg --configure -a it is the same.

Now I want to simple remove sendmail from the installation queue - but I can't simply do that, because apt-get always wants to configure sendmail first.

Is there a way to force apt-get to remove sendmail or set it to "configured"  - even though the package is not properly configured?

Comment: Maybe just a `dpkg -r sendmail` or `dpkg -P sendmail` will do it. The difference between `-r` and `-P` is that the last one will remove the whole programm including configuration.

Comment: The problem is - sendmail is not really installed... So dpkg -r sendmail dpkg -P sendmail does nothing. Maybe I should rephrase my question...

Comment: It seems there are some problems with your local package database. Normally the installation of sendmail works quite well. So no it get's a little bit in guessing the error. With `dpkg -l` you can get a list of installed packages, with the packagname afterwards you can limit the output, in your case it would be `dpkg -l "*sendmail*"`. Whats the output?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Mpr1EVVG (Sorry - in german)

Comment: According to "http://superuser.com/questions/428048/what-do-the-outputs-of-dpkg-l-mean" it just looks like the documentation is not fully installed, normally this happens in the `apt-get install` process right after the package-installation. I dont know if that's the cause but you can try `apt-get install -f` which should finish the installation of the sendmail documentation. But this is also just a little bit guessing. My Ubuntu installations tells me that sendmail-doc is only a recommended package so without trying i can't tell if the state is maybe right.

Comment: Sorry - I could now fix it by removing sendmail-bin... "sendmail" seems to be a meta-package or something... Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't thougt about this caveat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug and logged in http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717951

They have since fixed the bug, but if you currently are stuck in the infinite loop, that doesn't do you a ton of good.  In the response to the bug, user Flo posts a workaround where you change the update_db file, this worked for me:

```
    $diff update_db update_db.orig 
479,480c479,482
<               str=$(echo "$line" | head -n 1);
<               line=$(echo "$line" | tail -n +2);
---
>               str=$(echo "$line" | cut -d -f 1);
>               line=$(echo "$line" | cut -d -f 2-);
```